# Fastest way to replace a character in string in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a string (an excel range) something like "$A$1:$AB$1200".

I need to replace the row of starting range (here, 1) to some other value, say, 6 (so string becomes  "$A$6:$AB$1200")

I tried with below code, but it seems to getting too complicated

```
 Dim stRng As String
  stRng = Split(usdRange, ":")(0)

   Dim row2bRepl As Long
   row2bRepl = Right(stRng, Len(stRng) - InStr(2, stRng, "$"))

   usdRange = Replace(stRng, row2bRepl, hdrRow, InStr(2, stRng, "$"))
```

Any help on how to achieve this simpler?

TIA!

Comment: Fastest way or more convenient way?

Comment: Faster preferred!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty quick and very straight forward!

```
Sub test()
    Dim s1 As String, s2 As String

    s1 = "$A$1:$AB$1200"
    s2 = Intersect(Range(s1), Range(s1).Offset(5, 0)).Address 'evaluates to $A$6:$AB$1200
End Sub
```

As per your comments, here you can see it works perfectly well with a completely random range, only determined at runtime

```
Sub test()
    Dim usdRange As String, usdRange2 As String
    Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long
    lastRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(10, 100)
    lastCol = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 100)

    usdRange = Range("A1", Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Address
    usdRange2 = Intersect(Range(usdRange), Range(usdRange).Offset(5, 0)).Address

    Debug.Print usdRange, usdRange2
End Sub
```

Outputs the following, offsetting all ranges by the specified amount:

```
Old string    New string
$A$1:$CF$22   $A$6:$CF$22
$A$1:$AA$93   $A$6:$AA$93
$A$1:$N$82    $A$6:$N$82
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the range in example "$A$1:$AB$1200" is a dynamic one / known only at run time.. I have no information, so I cannot apply offset. However, the solution is nice :)

Comment: @NetTechie, you might need to explain your *actual* problem a bit better because from what I can tell this works perfectly with an unknown range -- see above edits as evidence

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work. It is not a lot simpler, but it looks simple:

```
Public Sub ReplaceString()

    Dim strInput    As String
    Dim lngFrom     As Long
    Dim lngTo       As Long

    strInput = "$A$1:$AB$1200"

    lngFrom = InStr(2, strInput, "$")
    lngTo = InStr(1, strInput, ":")

    Debug.Print Left(strInput, lngFrom) & "77" & Right(strInput, Len(strInput) - lngFrom-1)

End Sub
```

It takes the left and the right positions of the string and puts in the middle the new value, in this case `77`.

Comment: Thanks @Vityata, this works :)  But just want to know if this could still be simplified...